# dependent cascading drop down box list in AngularJS or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to implement dependent cascading drop down list in AngularJS. It is coming fine for: If I select any Country(say: `Country1`), then it's states(say: `State1`, `State2`, `State3`) are displaying in second drop down box(it's fine).

But my requirement is that: after displaying the above relevant states for a country, I need to display only that respective selected country for the given states in the first drop down box(say if I select either `State1 or State2 or State3 of Country1` then `Country1` should be displayed in the first drop down box(since `Country1` is having those states), and other countries(Country2, Country3) should be disabled or disappeared or not visible in the first drop down box). Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/nyg3d3zr/). Please help me that how can I implement it eihter in jquery or angularjs ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I know why you want to disable the other countries after selecting the Second drop down? you just want to know? Because what if  the user wants to go back and change the country?

Comment: @SMAhmed, thanks for your reply, actually this is my requirement and here User don't go back and can't change the country(once he selects state) in my requirement, so that's why. Please let me know.

Comment: Add ng-disabled="true" to the first drop down after selection of the second dropdown

Comment: @SMAhmed, how can I write that ? means if I write like: <select id="countryId" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in Countries" ng-disabled="true"> then my first drop down is in disabled mode displaying ?

Comment: @SMAhmed, yes, i got a solution, if I write ng-diabled="cities" in the first drop down box, then it is working as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

if I write ng-diabled="cities" in the first drop down box, then it is working fine as per my requirement.